# Retrieving table row information using ajax and pdo to display in bootstrap modal

Tags: ajax, pdo

Im trying to retrieve information from a table which is populated by a PDO array into a html table. I want to grab the row information when a user clicks on the 'delete button' for that row into a modal which i have for the delete confirmation.
I'm not sure how to go about doing this because the information returned is from the database and not hard-coded in.

```
     <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                        <thead>
                            <tr >
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                    Course Code
                                </th>

                                <th class="text-center">
                                    Course Title
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php foreach ($courses as $row) {
                            echo "<tr><td>";
                            echo $row['course_code'];
                            echo "</td><td>";
                            echo $row['course_title'];                              
                            echo "</td><td>";
                            echo '<p data-placement="top"
                                    data-toggle="tooltip"
                                    style="margin-left:18px"
                                    title="Delete">';
                            echo '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" 
                                    data-title="Delete" 
                                    data-toggle="modal" 
                                    data-target="#delete">';
                            echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" />';
                            echo '</button></p>';
                            echo "</tr>"; }
                            ?>
```

this is the code for the modal:

```
                                    <div id="delete" class="modal fade">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Record</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <p class="text-danger"><small>Are you sure you would like to delete this record?</small></p>
                                            <p class="text-danger"><small>You will not be able to un-do this action</small></p>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Course Title">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button id="can" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                            <button id= "upd" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

I know i will need AJAX to do this dynamically. Does anyone have any ideas of a solution? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target

You should add a new data attribute here:

```
 '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" 
 data-title="Delete" 
 data-index="yourItemIndex" <----- here
 data-toggle="modal" 
 data-target="#delete">';
```

Your script should be something like this:

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
// If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
// Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
var modal = $(this)
modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
})
```

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. My modal is actually triggered when the user clicks on the delete icon. My table has a unique id per row which pro fetches from the mysql database. would i be using that for the data-index? thanks

Comment: Yes. The database index should be used to fill the data-index attribute. Just make sure to validate, server side, if user has authorization to delete the returned index.

Comment: thanks, sorry but how would i get the value for the index? the html table is returned via the PDO query as an array.

Comment: If your PDO query is returning the id, and your id field is called "id", just do $row['id'], like you did for the course_title and course_code fields. If the query is not returning the id, then you need to modify it to include the returno of the id field.

Comment: course_code holds the id at the moment so would i repeat it with $row['course_code']? sorry for the questions. been struggling with this for some time today :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71919/discussion-between-arthur-samarcos-and-user90210).

Comment: okay so now it looks like 
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" 
data-title="Delete"
data-index="$row['course_code']"
data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#edit" >
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>

what would i need to put in the jquery for it to update the field in modal since the modal is triggered in the html? I've added another input attribute for course code.